# How can I send a text file to all open browsers on a website when a user submits a PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to make PHP send a text string to all browsers with a specific cookie when another browser submits a form

Comment: Let the client (open browsers) to check the server-side (PHP) using Ajax every x seconds. PHP can't send requests to clients and it should be the client request from the server

Comment: If the server sends something to browsers, using Websockets might be a good solution (maybe with a library like socket.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send the request from PHP to client - PHP is server side technology what does mean that the **client need to request server** then you can check for the cookie and send anything.

If you want to to anything like this you need to periodically fire some JS script to tell server to try to send data when for example some flag is set to true. The scenario would be then

```
sending (for example) AJAX request each 1s:
    if FORM_HAS_BEEN_SENT == true:
        check for a cookie and perform action

/*meanwhile*/ set FORM_HAS_BEEN_SENT on getting form request
```

Comment: Would that not overload the server though? Because the only time I need it to refresh is when the user submits a form

Comment: If you are hosting your site on old laptop then yup it will :) Every "normal" hosting should do the thing